# Change Windows 8.1 Language for System Messages

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, language

I purchased a Surface Pro 2 in the US and then moved to Spain. I just completed a warranty exchange here in Spain and received a Spanish version SP2.

I immediately changed the display language to English and almost all of the system is using the English language. The only time I'm seeing Spanish is when the system displays certain messages.

For example, when I restarted so updates could be installed, I see the message:

```
"Instalando actualizacion 25 de 40...No apague el equipo."
```

I can't figure out how to change those messages to English. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Open a command prompt as administrator, then run this command: `dism /online /get-intl & bcdedit /enum all` Then post here the full output.

Comment: @and31415, your comment was all I needed to track down what I needed to do. It's hard to do a Google search without knowing what I'm looking for. Throw it in an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: Probably a bit too late, but I've discovered a GUI way to do this: http://superuser.com/questions/948660/change-windows-7-8-10-system-language-welcome-screen-login-etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

In order to localize the system, these boot configurations need to be changed too:

- **Windows Boot Manager**
- **Windows Boot Loader**
- **Windows Memory Tester**
- **Resume from Hibernate**

To do so, follow these steps:

1. Open an [elevated command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-8).
2. Run the following commands after replacing `<lang>` with the installed culture name you want to use. A list can be found here: [National Language Support (NLS) API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx).

   ```
   for %G in (bootmgr,current,memdiag) do bcdedit /set {%G} locale <lang>
   for /f "tokens=2" %G in ('bcdedit /enum {bootmgr} ^| find /i "resumeobject"') do bcdedit /set %~G locale <lang>
   ```

   For example, to change the language to US English:

   ```
   for %G in (bootmgr,current,memdiag) do bcdedit /set {%G} locale en-US
   for /f "tokens=2" %G in ('bcdedit /enum {bootmgr} ^| find /i "resumeobject"') do bcdedit /set %~G locale en-US
   ```
3. Restart Windows to apply the changes.

### Further reading

- [Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)
- [BCDEdit /set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)