# How can I (really) change the Windows 10 system language without doing a clean install?

Tags: windows-10, language-pack

I bought a Surface Pro 3 with Norwegian Windows 8.1 pre installed, since upgraded to Windows 10. I want US English Windows. As I have found out the hard way, changing locale and input language is not enough, now I'm left with something in between, where 90% is in English (the language I want) and the rest in Norwegian (Windows update packages, boot sequence, etc.). Among other things, this prevents Cortana from working properly, and effectively blocks me from receiving Insider builds. I am aware that a clean install from a English iso would solve my problem, but this is not practical for a number of reasons. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: [Yes](http://superuser.com/questions/948660/change-windows-7-8-10-system-language-welcome-screen-login-etc), of course there is.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for pointing that out, man! Is it good form to delete my own question now, as it seems to be a duplicate?

Comment: I think it should be good to delete it. Try to see if it's possible.