# Windows 10 keeps installing programs in german (not the language I want)

Tags: windows, windows-10

I did the huge mistake in settings something to german during the windows 10 installation. I guess, keyboard or timezone. Now all programs install in german, which is really bad.

I checked region and language settings

[image]

and language settings

[image]

still things install in german / in the wrong language.

ideas?

Comment: Change the language while installing or later in the program itself? This doesn't work for some specific software that is shipped in one language only, though.

Comment: [Change the region and language](http://superuser.com/questions/948660/change-windows-7-8-10-system-language-welcome-screen-login-etc) to what you desire

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue, different language, but some programs were installing in English, others in Dutch.

Check your control panel > Region settings. Even if your language settings are all set to English, it's often the **Format** that is left in another language.
I've changed that to English as well, applied it to new users and all other profiles and that did it for me. Didn't even need to restart for it to take effect.

Comment: This is still an issue and it keeps getting worse. In Server 2022 and Windows 11 even some Event log messages are translated based on format not on language. It a horrible mess.

Comment: This question was about Windows 10. If you have similar issues with other operating systems, you should look specifically for those systems or open a new question.

Comment: True, but the locale settings are the same for all current Windows editions. Since MS doesn't seem to care there isn't much the user can do except change Formats to English and customize them from there.

Answer (score 0):

In **Control Panel**, open **Region**, click on **Administrative** tab and change the **Language for non-Unicode programs** by [Change system locale...]. If you have program installed in different language, you must has different language here.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was the non-Unicode in my case. My system W10 was installing HP G4010 scanner program in Greek. Switched non-Unicode from Greek to English in Regional and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score -2):

You made your mistake on the very first drop down before you even downloaded windows.  Just like me, you must reinstall, choosing English for the download instead.

Comment: How does this differ from the deleted answer you posted earlier?