# Change input language in login screen

Tags: windows-7, login, language, input-languages

My windows has 4 input languages, I have set the administrator password in a language other than English (the default language). Now I'm not able to login to my account as I'm not able to change the input language in login screen. I'm opening 'On Screen Keyboard' and I'm pressing Alt+Shift keys but the input language doesn't change. How should I change the input language in the login screen?

All answers I found including what jet offered as duplicate ([Change Windows 7/8/10 system language - welcome screen, login, etc](https://superuser.com/questions/948660/change-windows-7-8-10-system-language-welcome-screen-login-etc)) is involved accessing control panel and changing some settings while I'm stuck in login screen and can't move any forward

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Windows 7/8/10 system language - welcome screen, login, etc](http://superuser.com/questions/948660/change-windows-7-8-10-system-language-welcome-screen-login-etc). And it already has answer.

Comment: @Jet the question you mentioned is involved using control panel and changing settings while I'm stuck in login screen and can't move any forward

Comment: Try to reset your password, http://www.howtogeek.com/96630/how-to-reset-your-forgotten-windows-password-the-easy-way/

Comment: @Jusup resetting password is possible if you have already created a password reset disk. however I knew the password but was not able to type it as I was able to type it without changing input language. I finally managed to change the password from another pc

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani You should convert your comment into an answer. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @DavidPostill I know I have used stackoverflow a lot and answered my questions several times, actually I didn't do that because the way I recovered the password is not the answer to my question (which was changing input language on login screen) however I do that in case one wants to change the input language for the same reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to enter password (that I knew) because the the password was in another language and I wasn't able to change the input language. I finally ended up changing my password form another PC, using this program:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14284/How-to-change-a-user-s-password-on-a-remote-comput

There were lots of programs but this one worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows 7 then you can see language bar on top left side of login screen and you can select language from there, this thing can only be happen if language bar is active from control panel.

Comment: well in my case it was not active ;)