# How to change the language of Windows Automatic Repair interface?

Tags: windows-10, language

I have changed my windows language from Greek to English, but the Automatic Repair language is still Greek, and I want to change it to English.

[image: Automatic Repair]

<sup>*(image not mine)*</sup>

Yeah, this is the screen in Greek, and I want to change it to Enghish.

Comment: [This is handled by a different interface option.](http://superuser.com/questions/948660/change-windows-7-8-10-system-language-welcome-screen-login-etc?rq=1).  Best way to solve this problem, outside of making sure all regional choices are correct, is remove the Greet language pack all together.

Comment: @Ramhound This is not what I was looking for. The boot screen is still in greek (thx for linking though).

Comment: Have you removed the Greek Language pack?  If you cannot access Windows, its to late to change the language interface of WinRE, I suspect even if you can access it would require you to replace the recovery partition in its entireity.

Comment: @Ramhound I can access Windows. Do you mean I need to remove Greek language pack, reboot and then add it again?

Comment: @Ramhound I will roll-back your edit, 'cause I actually wanted that note under the picture.

Comment: I am suggesting you remove it.  As I said I suspect you would need to format the recovery partition and create it again to actually sovle the problem.  The reason you have a Greek WinRE installed is becaused you installed a Greek version of Windows 10, doesn't make sense, to offer multiple language, to a recovery environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39286/discussion-between---and-ramhound).

Comment: I inlined the screenshot for you, because the image currently is broken, in other words the image does not display.  **I won't fix it again.**

Comment: @Ramhound It displayed fine as is for me.

Comment: Well...It doesn't work for me.  I fixed it for you, and kept your comment, even though it isn't required

Comment: @Ramhound I can see in the Markdown code for this question that you have done something like `[![description][n]][n]` and later `[n]: url`. I'm amazed padding works for you. What system are you using?

Comment: That is how you inline the screenshot and make it clickable......There is nothing special about it.

Comment: @Ramhound You have double-inlined it...

Comment: I originally did that, I corrected that mistakem, in less then 5 seconds 35 minutes ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an admin prompt run "bcdedit".
You should see something like this:
[BCDedit output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3hbG.png)

To change language enter:

- bcdedit /set {current} locale en-US
- bcdedit /set {bootmgr} locale en-US

This should switch UI language to English also for recovery...
For [other languages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx), e.g. Italian you can use "... locale it-IT" etc.

Comment: Sorry it took me almost a year to realize this answer was posted, but for me it didn't work (Windows 10 now).

Comment: @EKons it should work. It always worked. Please can you check with the cmd "bcdedit" from admin prompt, if both "locale" entries have the desired locale code correctly set?

Comment: Hm, looks like it did work now, the settings have been preserved after a reboot.

Comment: This didn't work on my 20H2 Windows version. The recovery environment uses the original Windows language no matter what language settings are set in the system and int the bcdedit.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10 20H2, none of the answers helped me to change the recovery mode language. Here is what helped me to change the recovery mode language (and some system messages during boots and reboots) without editing images and making any manual manipulations with installation media:

1. Set all available system languages to the language of your choice (English in my case). This step may be excessive, but that's what I did: in `bcdedit`, in user settings, in the administrative language settings.
2. Run RegEdit end go to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language` key where change the `InstallLanguage` key value to the language id you want to be set in the recovery:

[image: regedit installlanguage]

[Refer to the list of language codes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/70feba9f-294e-491e-b6eb-56532684c37f) ([or here](https://www.w3.org/International/ms-lang.html)) and enter the hex value of your choice (`0409` for `en-US`).

3. Reboot your PC.
4. [Download the official MediaCreationTool](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691209) and run it. Choose the `Upgrade this PC` option:

[image: mediacreationtool upgrade]

That's it! Follow the linear progress to upgrade your Windows. In the end, I've got the English language everywhere including the recovery mode and the most recent Windows version with all programs and settings kept.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add the corresponding language packs for each package in the image, including the base Windows PE language pack.

For example, when you add the French (fr-fr) language pack to the base Windows PE image, and then to each of the optional components that are present in the default Windows RE image

You may refer to this detailed process:

Walkthrough: Create a Windows RE Image

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744525(v=ws.10).aspx

Adding Languages

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825125.aspx#BKMK_AddLanguagePacks

Comment: What do you mean with "WinPE language packs"?

Comment: I suspect the author actually is trying to suggest you change the language pack of your WinRE installation, that is located in your recovery partition, instead of WinPE

Comment: @Ramhound I don't have a separate recovery partition.

Comment: I could have downvoted, but I haven't got enough reputation yet.

Comment: So how did you boot into the Automatic Repair screenshot, which is in Greek, but illustrated in your screenshot?  The environement, Automatic Repair resides in, is WinRE which is typically located on its own partition.  Edit your question to provide more specific details.  The information in the link articles, **explains percisely**, how to achieve your goals.  Once you create the image itself, you would just replace the image your actually using, by using the DISM tool.

Comment: @Ramhound Okay, reviving this post (since I still have the problem), I think what you mean by recovery partition is in fact the 'System' partition?

Comment: No; that's not what I mean. WinRE isn't contain on the system partition, its contained on the same disk normally.  I don't answer questions in comments, to answers, endless cycle.

Answer (score 0):

when i downloaded my windows recovery, it came with the option of only choosing 5 languages, all in european countries and none of them was english. I had to install windows using google translate. after installing, i downloaded english language pack after several efforts, and it did manage to change the display language to English, however not everything was changed. when you boot the computer, the language was in danish, and when you would get an error from windows it would be displayed in danish

I tried the solution of using bcdedit on command prompt. Command prompt showed me it has accepted the commands, however nothing happend. I then went ahead to follow this option of changing the language registry files, as illustrated above and it worked great. it worked perfectly. Thank you for this hack....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1103405)