# Windows 11 - Recreate recovery partition

Tags: windows-11, recovery-partition

I accidentally installed windows 11 with UK language. I managed to switch my OS to en-Us display and keyboard language but my recovery is still in UK (The keyboard layout is different and I cant use symbols). I tried a few commands so I could change my recovery language but it ended up messing with it and now I have no recovery (The partition is still there) How can I recreate my recovery partition with en-us languge/keyboard layout without format or reinstall?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the language of Windows Automatic Repair interface?](https://superuser.com/questions/1072904/how-to-change-the-language-of-windows-automatic-repair-interface)

The recovery locale is obviously set to en-UK, that's why it is using UK keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to download the
[Windows 11 Installation Media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11)
and then
[Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).

This will "upgrade" Windows 11 to itself and redo the recovery partition.
Be sure to pick the right language.