# Advanced boot is in different language

Tags: boot, windows-11, language

I purchased secondhand laptop from Germany and during setup of Windows 11 I kept the original language (German) and also added English language. Then I continued to set up everything in English. Later I decided to remove German because I didn’t need it. But once I had to use advanced boot (blue screen boot) option I found out it is still in German. I checked my registry and settings and it all seems to be set up for English. Do I have to use Windows 11 creation tool? But I don’t want to loose my apps, data, nor drivers. Especially drivers, because it is pain installing them and finding correct ones.  [image: Picture of registry keys]

Answers for the other “similar” that I tried [How to change the language of Windows Automatic Repair interface?](https://superuser.com/questions/1072904/how-to-change-the-language-of-windows-automatic-repair-interface) question didn’t work. My question is whether there are still more options how to resolve my issue before resolving into Windows reinstall. My question is also regarding whole advanced boot menu being in different language and not just part of it.

Screw you admins.

Comment: “Do I have to use Windows 11 creation tool?” - Why would you reinstall Windows if you can install and change the language of the interface of Windows? Change the locale of the machine

Comment: Does this answer your question perhaps? https://superuser.com/questions/1072904/how-to-change-the-language-of-windows-automatic-repair-interface

Comment: I already read those and I also “used bcdedit /set {current} locale en-US” and
“bcdedit /set {bootmgr} locale en-US” commands. But it didn’t solve the problem.

Comment: If proposed answers don't help, add that info to your question and explain what didn't work.

Comment: How am I supposed to know why it didn’t work? It just didn’t.

Comment: By debugging. Mention what you tried and what were the exact results, even if you sum all our attempts up with "it's still in German". Reopening based on that edit will be 100% impossible. Including `Edit` keyword is not needed BTW, edit history can be checked.

Comment: Instead of adding "EDIT", you could instead add "Update 1", "Update 2", etc, to indicate the progress of your efforts more clearly.

Comment: I already mentioned what I tried. Checking that all language settings are set to English (system language, regional format, location, UEFI BIOS), I even checked those values in registry. I also tried the commands that I already posted above. Basically everything as in the other thread except reinstalling Windows. Which was my question about. Whether there are still some other options left or not.

Comment: I have whole advanced startup in German. Not only Windows automatic repair option.

Comment: Music2myear I typed “edit” because there was a notification that I should edit my question and without word “edit” it still got closed. I thought this stuff might be handled by some word sensitive bot. I edited my question only as attempt to preserve it.