# Keyboard Layout is deleted however it still shows up in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-layout

I have windows 10, i removed the english layout in the keyboard options and left the polish one, but it occasionally still switches back to the english one, when i click the "ENG PLP" in the right bottom corner of my screen it still shows that there are two languages. Is it a bug? I don't want to have my system language polish.

Comment: When you installed Windows was language version was it?  If you don't what your system language to be polish why did you remove the English keyboard layout.  You should just change the system language for your system.  [Change Windows 7/8/10 system language - welcome screen, login, etc](http://superuser.com/questions/948660/change-windows-7-8-10-system-language-welcome-screen-login-etc)