# Windows 10 search results of settings and control panel are in different language

Tags: windows-10, language, windows-search, search-indexing

I'm from Belgium, so my Windows 10 is in Dutch.

To try something, I changed the display langugae to English. Everything was English, no problem. But when I changed it back to Dutch, everything changed back to Dutch except the search results of settings and control panel.

[image: Here's a screenshot]

As you can see in the screenshot, everything except the search results from settings are displayed in Dutch. The results from settings and control panel are still English...

How do I fix this? I've tried rebuilding the index, removing Windows.edb and even edit the registry.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you use the dutch word for settings what are the results?  What language packs do you have installed?

Comment: Inside the settings I can use Dutch words. But when I use Dutch words for settings in the search bar, i can't find them. And I only have the Dutch language pack installed.

Comment: If thats the case, then the dutch language pack doesn't contain dutch translations for those UWPs.  Do you know for a fact that those results should be dutch?  Not all LPs are created equal.

Comment: Yes I know that for sure. Before I tried the English language pack, all the results were in Dutch. Searching inside the settings and control panel using Dutch word is no problem because everything is displayed in Dutch. So yes, I know for a fact.

Comment: [Change Windows 7/8/10 system language - welcome screen, login, etc](http://superuser.com/questions/948660/change-windows-7-8-10-system-language-welcome-screen-login-etc) verify your settings.

Comment: I already did that a hundred times. Every settings is Dutch (Belgium). Yet the search results for settings or control panel are still English...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50141/discussion-between-mason-and-ramhound).