# Way to switch Windows 10 user interface to English

Tags: windows-10, language

I have Windows 10 Pro 1607 installed with the support of the English and Russian languages. System language - Russian. I want to change the interface language to English, but not lose the ability to type in Russian.

1. I'm try to switch language order in `Control panel` --> `Language` -
   no result. See screenshot.
   [image]
2. I'm try to select `English (United States)` interface language in `Control panel` --> `Language` --> `Additional parameters` but opposite language `English (United States)` is written  `(not available)`, and it's selection return no results. Perhaps i need to install any component? See screenshot.

[image: English language selection returns no result]

Of course, I tried to reboot after each change of setting.

How to change the **user interface** language?

**UPD.** @DavidPostill marks my question as duplicate of [this issue](https://superuser.com/questions/948660/change-windows-7-8-10-system-language-welcome-screen-login-etc). But it described change of language on the *login screen* and the *default profile*. And i need to change my users account interface language, not login screen or default profile.

**UPD2.**
In language options screen for `English (United States)` writen that language pack not available.
[image]

This troubles only with `English (United States)` language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Windows 7/8/10 system language - welcome screen, login, etc](http://superuser.com/questions/948660/change-windows-7-8-10-system-language-welcome-screen-login-etc)

Comment: @DavidPostill Nothing in common. I ask how to change the user interface language. In [this issue](http://superuser.com/questions/948660/change-windows-7-8-10-system-language-welcome-screen-login-etc) described change of language on the *login screen* and the *default profile*!

Comment: [How to Change the Display Language in Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/232659/how-to-change-the-display-language-in-windows-10/)

Comment: @DavidPostill i describe in question that it's do not work for me. `English (Unated States)` selecteble but no effect.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots?

Comment: @DavidPostill i'm added screenshot. Sorry - I can not upload to Imgur

Comment: I've switched it to imgur for you. Unfortunately it does help as I don't read Russian :/

Comment: That's why I want the English interface, but he switched to any other than English!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like if you have to OS installed in Russian with English only available as input-language for the keyboard.
In the Languages settings panel first add English as 2nd language (if not already done so).
Initially that will only add it as input-language for the keyboard.
To the right of the language there is now an "Options" link (whatever it is called in Russian).
When you click that you will get a 2nd screen from where you can download and install the Language Pack, which adds that language as an available Display Language.

When it is available as Display-language you can set it as the default Display-language for the various options that support this: System-language, login-screen-language and user-language.

**EDIT:**
I just did some reading up on the subject.
What I wrote above is valid for ANY language except English.

English is NOT available as a LIP (Language Interface Pack) so it can not be added AFTER the installation of the system.
In order to get English the language must be integrated in the installation medium itself. Either directly placed there in the original Microsoft image or it can be integrated (using DISM) as extra language to an already existing installation medium. (You can also use DISM to remove it if you feel so inclined.)

Most international versions of Windows 10 include English as 1 of the base languages (and add 1 or more other languages to the installation medium). But there are also Windows 10 versions around (especially OEM/pre-install versions for a specific market) that ONLY have a non-English language available.

Anyway: English must be integrated in order to be available as Display-Language. (It is also NOT possible to do an upgrade-installation to an existing Windows 10 without English, to add English during the upgrade.)

So it seems that you can't add English to your Windows 10 installation unless you wipe the installation and do a full re-install using an installation medium that has English integrated (and add Russian as a 2nd language later).

Comment: I update question. Written that  language pack not available.