# Why do UK Windows 10 users get US keyboard when signing on to Server 2012 R2 domain

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, windows-server-2012-r2

When my UK users sign in for the first time to a Windows 10 PC, connecting to a Server 2012 R2 DC, they get a US keyboard layout which is of course incorrect & confusing. When I change Control Panel 'Language' settings and add English (United Kingdom) and promote it above US English, and make sure that 'Region' settings are also UK - all is well. Until they sign in on for the first time to another Windows 10 PC when they are back to a US keyboard, and so on. Is this a problem with Windows 10 or is there something I need to do at the Server 2012 end?  The server certainly knows it's in the UK so I'm guessing this is some Windows 10 glitch.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that for some reason the default language for a new user on W10 is 'English (United States)'  (even though the PC is in and set up for the UK). To change this odd default, you go to the Control Panel then Region (check your country is the default) then the 'Administrative' tab then click 'Copy Settings' and make sure to check the 2 options at the foot of this screen 'Welcome screen and system accounts' and 'New user accounts'.  You will see that the language for these will now be the same as the default.  So new users will get the correct language.
(this is essentially also answered here here [Change Windows 7/8/10 system language - welcome screen, login, etc](https://superuser.com/questions/948660/change-windows-7-8-10-system-language-welcome-screen-login-etc)  )