# Keyboard and Language input windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, language

[image: Language bottom right, Settings top left]

In the picture above you see in the settings window that I have set Swedish as standard language, but on the login screen it says "Welcome" in English not Swedish. And when I start playing a game, let's say TF2 then it automatically adds English(US) keyboard which you can see in the bottom right corner of the picture, but in the settings there is no keyboard added.
Check the picture below for confirmation:

[image: Language settings in control panel]

How do I stop Windows 10 from adding additional languages and only use Swedish?
I have checked for answers related to my problem here: [Windows 10 input language issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1165669/windows-10-input-language-issue) but I can't be adding and removing that language all the time, there  must be a permanent fix for this.

Edit:
This [Change Windows 7/8/10 system language - welcome screen, login, etc](https://superuser.com/questions/948660/change-windows-7-8-10-system-language-welcome-screen-login-etc) is not what I'm looking for because the default language is on the welcome screen, login screen and everywhere else I have checked it multiple times. But it happens to add language each time I start TF2 on the computer, which is very annoying.

Edit nr. 2:
It doesn't add keyboard layout when playing NFS:MW.

Edit nr. 3:
PowerShell output:

```
EnglishName InputMethodTips
----------- ---------------
Swedish     {041D:0000041D}
```

Edit nr. 4:
PowerShell ISE output:

```
EnglishName InputMethodTips
----------- ---------------
Swedish     {041D:0000041D}
```

Comment: Forgive me, perhaps I am a bit confused:  you said *"it says 'Welcome' in English not Swedish,"* but then you said *"How do I stop Windows 10 from adding additional languages and only use Swedish?"*  Finally, you said *"Not possible because it is already on welcome screen."* That sounds like conflicting information to me.  Do you want Swedish to be used everywhere, or not?

Comment: It is swedish everywhere check this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ9Um.png it just adds English(US) each time I open TF2 or NFS:MW

Comment: I'm sorry but it is only you that is confused right now becuase it actually did say english in welcome screen and swedish everywhere else but I fixed that problem, and the problem that remains a problem is that windows adds English(US) to keyboard layouts but not making it visible in settings. And I want to stop Windows 10 from adding lets say English(US) which it does when I open a game.

Comment: `Get-WinUserLanguageList | Format-Table -Property EnglishName, InputMethodTips`. Run this command in Powershell (and run it in  Powershell elevated as well). Then, [edit] your question and provide output. Do not post picture(s), copy&paste text from Powershell window rather, please.