# How to set language for error message in IE F12 developer tools?

Tags: internet-explorer, language, internet-explorer-11, developer-tools

I use IE in Czech. Sometimes (like today) the Czech error message doesn't allow to reconstruct the Google-friendly English version, so I would prefer to use the developer tools in English. I didn't find any option to do it there. So I changed the settings to English (and even removed Czech) in IE's Internet Options (or how is it called in English), restarted my computer, but the F12 tools are still in Czech, including the error messages.

So how to change the language to something other than the computer's locale? Changing the whole system's locale [including system messages](https://superuser.com/q/796981/373304) would be overkill.